# How to replace an image in a button to remain as the new image after the button is pressed?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm creating a game and the user has to press a button, when he presses the button the image of the button should change permanently...

```
- (IBAction)secondHintq:(id)sender {
hintView.text = @"Type in text here 2";
}
```

The outlet to the button is called:

```
candleChangeOne
```

how is this done?

Comment: Have you read the class reference for UIButton?  Specifically theimageForState: method?

Comment: No I haven't, have you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this:

```
- (IBAction)secondHintq:(id)sender 
{
    UIButton *button = sender;
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YourImage"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    hintView.text = @"Type in text here 2";
}
```